# Grouping and then Mutating new column based on content

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to figure out a way to group data, and then create a column based on the content of the grouped rows.

Sample `df` to be manipulated

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
              ~name, ~position, ~G,
      "DJ LeMahieu",      "1B", 40,
      "DJ LeMahieu",      "2B", 75,
      "DJ LeMahieu",      "3B", 52,
        "Max Muncy",      "1B", 65,
        "Max Muncy",      "2B", 70,
        "Max Muncy",      "3B", 35,
  "Whit Merrifield",      "2B", 82,
  "Whit Merrifield",      "OF", 61
  )
```

I then want this content to be grouped at the name level.  I want to create a new column called extra_position.  This column would be a concatenate of the content in the position column separated by a "/".  Example output below:

```
output_df <- tibble::tribble(
              ~name,  ~extra_position,
      "DJ LeMahieu", "1B/2B/3B",
        "Max Muncy", "1B/2B/3B",
  "Whit Merrifield",    "2B/OF"
  )
```

I'd like to stay within the `tidyverse` if possible.  In addition, I'm curious to know whether you can also control the order of the data being concatenated.  For example, can you make DJ LeMahieu's `extra_position` content show as: `"3B/2B/1B"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'name', `paste` or (`str_c`) the 'position' column by `collapse`ing the elements to a single string

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(extra_position = str_c(position, collapse="/"))
```

If we need to `rev`erse the order

```
df %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(position = str_c(rev(position), collapse="/"))
```

Or if it is based on the values

```
df %>% 
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarise(position = str_c(gtools::mixedsort(position,
            decreasing = TRUE), collapse="/"))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(extra_position = paste(position, collapse="/")), .(name)]
```

---

In `base R`, use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(position ~ name, df, paste, collapse="/")
```

Comment: If you also want to control the order of the concatenated data, you can add `arrange(desc(position))` or `arrange(position)`, before doing the `summarise` to concatenate them in descending or ascending order, respectively.